# Can't Play an MP4 Video in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: video, mp4

I am not able to play this video file in my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS OS:
https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-OpenCV-4-with-Python/blob/master/Motion%20Detector/airplanes.mp4

I installed ubuntu-restricted-extras in an attempt to solve this problem. This did not make a difference.

I tried several video players. None played it. The most detailed error message I got about this is from the Kylin Video app. This error message is:

```
/usr/bin/mpv --no-config --no-quiet --terminal --no-msg-color --input-file=/dev/stdin --msg-level=ffmpeg/demuxer=error --gpu-context=x11egl --no-fs --vd-lavc-threads=4 --hwdec=no --sub-auto=fuzzy --vo=xv, --ao=player_default, --no-input-default-bindings --input-vo-keyboard=no --no-input-cursor --cursor-autohide=no --no-keepaspect --wid=75497491 --monitorpixelaspect=1 --osd-level=1 --osd-scale=1 --osd-bar-align-y=0.6 --sub-ass --embeddedfonts --sub-ass-line-spacing=0 --sub-scale=1 --sub-font=Arial --sub-color=#ffffffff --sub-shadow-color=#ff000000 --sub-border-color=#ff000000 --sub-border-size=0.75 --sub-shadow-offset=2.5 --sub-font-size=50 --sub-bold=no --sub-italic=no --sub-margin-y=8 --sub-margin-x=20 --sub-codepage=UTF-8 --sub-pos=100 --volume=55 --cache=auto --screenshot-template=cap_%F_%p_%02n --screenshot-format=jpg --screenshot-directory=/home/stephen/Pictures/kylin_video_screenshots --audio-channels=2 --audio-pitch-correction=yes --af-add=lavfi=[firequalizer=gain='cubic_interpolate(f)':zero_phase=on:wfunc=tukey:delay=0.027:gain_entry='entry(0,0);entry(62.5,0);entry(125,0);entry(250,0);entry(500,0);entry(1000,0);entry(2000,0);entry(4000,0);entry(8000,0);entry(16000,0)'] --volume-max=110 --term-playing-msg=MPV_VERSION=${=mpv-version:}
INFO_VIDEO_WIDTH=${=width}
INFO_VIDEO_HEIGHT=${=height}
INFO_VIDEO_ASPECT=${=video-aspect}
INFO_VIDEO_FPS=${=container-fps:${=fps}}
INFO_VIDEO_FORMAT=${=video-format}
INFO_VIDEO_CODEC=${=video-codec}
INFO_AUDIO_FORMAT=${=audio-codec-name}
INFO_AUDIO_CODEC=${=audio-codec}
INFO_AUDIO_RATE=${=audio-params/samplerate}
INFO_AUDIO_NCH=${=audio-params/channel-count}
INFO_LENGTH=${=duration:${=length}}
INFO_DEMUXER=${=current-demuxer:${=demuxer}}
INFO_SEEKABLE=${=seekable}
INFO_TITLES=${=disc-titles}
INFO_CHAPTERS=${=chapters}
INFO_TRACKS_COUNT=${=track-list/count}
METADATA_TITLE=${metadata/by-key/title:}
METADATA_ARTIST=${metadata/by-key/artist:}
METADATA_ALBUM=${metadata/by-key/album:}
METADATA_GENRE=${metadata/by-key/genre:}
METADATA_DATE=${metadata/by-key/date:}
METADATA_TRACK=${metadata/by-key/track:}
METADATA_COPYRIGHT=${metadata/by-key/copyright:}
INFO_MEDIA_TITLE=${=media-title:}
INFO_STREAM_PATH=${stream-path}
 --audio-client-name=KylinVideo --term-status-msg=STATUS: ${=time-pos} / ${=duration:${=length:0}} P: ${=pause} B: ${=paused-for-cache} I: ${=core-idle} VB: ${=video-bitrate:0} AB: ${=audio-bitrate:0} /home/me/Projects/Udemy Classes/Computer Vision and Machine Learning With OpenCV 4/Computer Vision and Machine Learning with OpenCV 4/airplanes.mp4

Error parsing option input-file (option not found)
Setting commandline option --input-file=/dev/stdin failed.
Exiting... (Fatal error)
```

What has gone wrong here? Do I still have a missing codec? Or is this file corrupt?

My system:

```
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16-Core Processor (2200 MHz)
Memory: 128724 MB (Used: 394 MB)
Concurrency: 32
OS Version: Linux 5.17.0-1020-oem #21-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 14 09:33:24 UTC 2022 x86_64
Graphics Card Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090/PCIe/SSE2
Graphics Card Memory: 24564 MB

OpenGL Version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 535.161.07
```

Comment: I got a corrupt file when downloading with wget but the file (h.264 and aac) played fine when downloaded via browser. Which method did you use?

Comment: I used the Firefox browser to download the mp4 file. Also, after I saw your comment I also tried wget. Either way the result was a downloaded file that was not playable. Which browser did you use to get a playable download?

Comment: Hmmm... well I used Firefox as well. Do you just need the file to continue your work? I can temporarily post the file on my own server space for you to successfully download...